# error message related to mergeCloseModules function

Tags: r

I'm using WGCNA R package to define cluster of coherent genes. I faced an 
error when I tried to merge modules using "mergeCloseModules". There error  was: "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". I couldn't find any explanation!  Would you please guide me?

Comment: It will be difficult to help if you do not provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask